Identify this 1990s robot/mech TV series
I remember this was a robot/mech anime TV series from the 1990s (and it's not Visions of Escaflowne).
I also remember that pilots would get inside robots and would get a big diamond attached to their hearts. Over time, the pilots would get weak if they fought for too long. The diamond was kind of fusioned in their chest. The robots weren't very big.

Yes because the serie that I'm talking about the pilots had this big diamond star in their chest and they kinda fusioned with their robots, I think the robots were human sized or a bit bigger, something close to the "Centurions" cartoons.

Please help me!, and thank you!.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

I'm assuming that it was animated? (Though, please say so if it was live-action, as that would significantly reduce the possibilities.) And do you remember whether the show was American or Japanese? (Or from another country entirely?)

I think you're looking for Tekkaman Blade!



This is the transformation. I'm pretty sure no other series uses diamonds in this way.



They use a diamond to transform into the Tekkaman or Technoman!




Hmmmm I don't see the big dimond in the chest of the pilots, I remember that they kinda fusioned with their mech. Their hearts were pretty much the diamond,the dimond was alot bigger than the ones in Vision of escaflowne. I think that everytime they fusioned with the robot,the diamond played a big role.

Please help me and thank you!

@tltrambo yes, Tekkaman had a crystal that is required for transformation. At one point it is damaged and that causes issues for them. And the longer they stay transformed Tekkaman would get brainwashed into a killer.
